# SQL Server 2008 storage of xs:date and xs:time shifted to GMT

Tags: sql-server-2008, utc

Is there any way to prevent SQL Server 2008 from interpolating dates and times passed as xs:date and xs:time to UTC?  Currently we're running the server at EST and any times passed in are kicked back -05:00.  We'd like to prevent this as it's a very serious issue.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions were to either use full ISO 8601 data, or what I did instead: interpolate the data server-side as we operate from a fixed timezone.  Since much of the XML source data could be brewed the 8601 option was too complex for our needs.